# IntersectionObserver always showing as "in view" when its not

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm trying to get `IntersectionObserver` working for my page. The HTML looks like:

```
<div id="feature-blocks">
    <div class="block left">
        <img src="/2022/css/sass/font-awesome/pngs/black/48/solid-icons.png" />
        <h2>Lots of Digital Images</h2>
        <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block bottom">
            <img src="/2022/css/sass/font-awesome/pngs/black/48/solid-object-group.png" />
            <h2>Online Graphics Editor</h2>
            <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block right">
            <img src="/2022/css/sass/font-awesome/pngs/black/48/solid-copyright.png" />
            <h2>Copyright Safe Images</h2>
            <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block left">
            <img src="/2022/css/sass/font-awesome/pngs/black/48/solid-laptop.png" />
            <h2>Access From Any Device</h2>
            <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block bottom">
            <img src="/2022/css/sass/font-awesome/pngs/black/48/solid-grin-hearts.png" />
            <h2>Unlimited Access</h2>
            <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block right">
            <img src="/2022/css/sass/font-awesome/pngs/black/48/solid-handshake.png" />
            <h2>Commercial Use</h2>
            <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

The JS I have is:

```
const features_blocks = document.querySelectorAll('#feature-blocks .block');
var observer_features = new IntersectionObserver( entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        console.log("TEST: "+ entry.intersectionRatio);
        if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
          console.log('in the view');
        } else {
          console.log('out of view');
        }
      });
    }, { root: document.querySelector('#feature-blocks'), rootMargin: '0px', threshold: 0.5 }
);

features_blocks.forEach(f => {
observer_features.observe(f);
});
```

The problem is, it always shows as "in view" even when its not!

[image]

I've tried playing with the thresholds, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. What am I doing wrong?

An example of what I'm seeing: https://jsfiddle.net/youradds/7ad34ebh/4/ (check out the console log when scrolling)

Comment: what may help is a snippet that demonstrates your issue

Comment: @Bravo is this any good? https://jsfiddle.net/youradds/7ad34ebh/4/ . You should be able to see in the console that it always shows as "visible"

Comment: what I can see is that the callback is called exactly once .... although, removing `{ root: document.querySelector('#feature-blocks'), rootMargin: '0px', threshold: 0.5 }` argument, it seems to call the callback more often - perhaps you need to think about what intersection you wish to observe

Comment: @Bravo ahh that was it! M understanding was that `root: xxx` defines which DOM element to look for the items ("to listen to"). Removing that makes it work correctly now - although I did have to tweak `if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {` to `if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {` , otherwise it showed right away (even if only margionally visible). Could you please put that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const features_blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.feature-blocks');
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    const block = entry.target.querySelector('.block');
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log('in the view');
    } else {
      console.log('out of view');
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.feature-blocks'));

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  Array.from(features_blocks).forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(features_blocks);
    observer.observe(element);
  });
});
```

```css
#feature {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  .block {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      align-self: center;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="feature">
  <div class="feature-blocks">
    <div class="block left">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
      <h2>Lots of Digital Images</h2>
      <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="feature-blocks">
    <div class="block bottom">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
      <h2>Online Graphics Editor</h2>
      <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-blocks">
    <div class="block right">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
      <h2>Copyright Safe Images</h2>
      <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-blocks">
    <div class="block left">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
      <h2>Access From Any Device</h2>
      <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-blocks">
    <div class="block bottom">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
      <h2>Unlimited Access</h2>
      <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-blocks">
    <div class="block right">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
      <h2>Commercial Use</h2>
      <p>foo bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The key change here was that you needed to wrap each block with the "feature-blocks". This is working right now and can see this live in the Url:  https://jsfiddle.net/dboua6j8/31/ too.

Comment: IDs must be unique in HTML, multiple `id="feature-blocks"` on the same page is invalid markup.

Comment: @DBS - thanks amended these to class